# Show the convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a real sequence, $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ converges to $k$. I need to show that the sequence $\left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)$ converges to $k$. I should probably use the definition of limits, suppose $\epsilon>0$ is given, then there is $N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_n-k|<\epsilon
$$
I am not sure how to arrive to $\left|\frac{a_n}{n}-k\right|<\epsilon$.

Comment: For $m\gt n$, show $a_m$ is close to $a_n+(m-n)k$, so $a_m/m$ is close to $k+(a_n/m)-(kn)/m$, and for fixed $n$ the other terms go to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** use [a good property of Cesaro mean](http://planetmath.org/cesaromean) working with the sequence $(a_{n+1}-a_n,n\geqslant 1)$ instead of $(a_n,n\geqslant 1)$.